# Job application website farms links to my social network profiles. Is it illegal, sketchy, or neither?

Tags: ethics, applications, background-check, privacy

I submitted an application to a company through Gild.com, which is a service the company I'm applying to is using.

I entered my resume and my basic contact info, and was presented with a list of 20 or so social network profiles, most of which that I'd totally forgotten about.

Is it just me who feels this is sketchy?

Comment: Are the profiles from other people/companies who also use this site?

Comment: No its pretty left field stuff. Google plus, twitter. Flickr, even some sites I don't know what they sre

Comment: @JoeStrazzere cancelled and sent an angellist message to the company instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These days, assume that any company you apply to will research you on line. They're allowed to use anything that's public information, which includes most social sites.

If you don't want employers to see something, it is your responsibility to keep it unpublished. Since companies may change their system's behavior and their privacy policies with little or notice, that means don't post anything you aren't willing to have exposed. And think twice before posting even in supposedly private services.

Basic principle: If you aren't paying for a service, you aren't the customer -- you're the product, and you're being sold to others.

Sorry, but that's the nature of the Net.

Comment: I guess what bothers me (in addition to them showing me these links and not thinking it's creepy) is that they are able to get so much info from just my email address. If I make a anonymous username for exactly this reason they can still find me by my email, which I didn't realize.

Comment: pretty much anything on the net is fair game. Information is currency so a LOT of innocuous seeming things are collecting every bit of info they can about everyone..

Comment: @max This is one example why you should use multiple email addresses. Also I dont see anything creepy here. You could, for example, put someone's email address into Facebook search box, and Facebook will show you the profile linked to that email. This company seems to have just automated that.

Comment: are you realy sure about "They're allowed to use anything that's public information" ?

Comment: Short of legally actionable discrimination, in the US, _yes_ I'm sure. Never put anything on line that you wouldn't be willing to discuss with a potential boss.

Comment: Also keep in mind there are numerous "caching" sites out there that farms social media sites and caches them into a searchable database. So basically anything you post today will appear for decades even if you erase it. Most of these sites have ways to scrub your info but it requires you to be proactive and do so on a case-by-case basis. It's probably best to limit your online footprint to minimize any current or future problems.

Comment: And don't assume that using different user IDs is sufficient to separate two accounts. Images can be face-matched, connections to other users can be analyzed, writing styles and expertise likewise.

Comment: (Though the response I'm seeing from modern college students is tending towards "Privacy? That's, like, sooooo 20th Century.")

Comment: @keshlam You're using a product, though. It's reasonable to assume that since you are part of the product they will use your information to sell off or market for their own purpose. Data is stored on a unknown media and it's safe to assume that whatever information you put on it can be browsed by a unknown person. As such it's best to limit the information you put out into a public space. You wouldn't scream, "I live at X, and I'm Y years old!" when walking into every business, so why would you do that on social media?

Comment: @dan: I don't think I said anything which disagrees with that...

Comment: @keshlam You are right indeed (as you almost always are!), multiple email addresses help reduce the "surface area for the attack" (if you will), but one should not be foolish enough to make it blatantly obvious. Using the same photo on both accounts after the trouble is epitome of foolishness, as is using nearly similar usernames (masked_man/masked.man) or same name on different sites (masked.man AT gmail/hotmail). Posting "this world is completely worthless" publicly on my "real" Facebook wall would also be bad. Avoiding these is still not foolproof, but keeps out the naive scammers at least.

Comment: ***General reminder:*** That applies to here on SE too. Assume your bosses also read Stack Exchange, and think about whether you want to sanitize your question and/or post it anonymously or from a rhrow-away account. My approach is to not say anything I wouldn't be willing to discuss with an interviewer or boss, but I grant that isn't always practical.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that the site is actually doing you a service by reminding you of sites that you have accounts with but may have forgotten about. Many employers will do a public social media research on new hires and so you have to assume that any employee that you are applying to will see all of those sites. This way you can go verify that there is nothing publicly visible on then that an employer would find objectionable.

By doing a quick search of their own and showing that info to the job seeker, Guild.com is obviously hoping to strengthen candidates who apply through them.